# MVC (Razor) Json error (500 internal server error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Controller Action is:

```
    public ActionResult GetStatesByCountry(string countryCode)
    {
        return Json(DropDownHelper.GetState(countryCode).Select(x => new { value = x.Code, text  x.Name }));
    }
```

When I Debug using firebug, I got following error.

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

Comment: What does the debugger have to say about the error?

Comment: It says To allow GET requests for JSON. I dnt know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

```
return Json(DropDownHelper.GetState(countryCode).Select(x => new { value = x.Code, text = x.Name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` to the method, because the default value is [DenyGet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
public ActionResult GetStatesByCountry(string countryCode)
{
    return Json(DropDownHelper.GetState(countryCode).Select(x => new { value = x.Code, text  x.Name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```